# SNR of simulated signal (no background)

Tags: snr

I have the simulated signal of an MRI measurement distorted with Gaussian noise of mean value = mean signal magnitude and sd = 1% of mean signal magnitude.

How can I calculate the SNR? I think that SNR=mean signal/sd of Gaussian noise = e.g. 100/1 = 100. Is it a correct way? Could you recommend some source?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) is pretty comprehensive...

Answer (score 2):

Standard deviation (SD) and RMS are related and, to quote [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square): -

> Standard deviation being the root mean square of a signal's variation
>   about the mean

So now you have the RMS value of the noise and SNR is signal/noise (both RMS terms).